# Disecting a log diff transformation for time series analysis and prediction

Tags: programming, time-series, finance-mathematics, machine-learning, prediction

I have been working in a predictive ML model that uses financial time-series as predictor variables. In one of the academic papers I used as reference, and to do feature engineering for building the predictors they recommended doing a log diff transformation of the price.

In Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

# download the S&P500 
df = yf.download('^GSPC')
df['Close_log_diff'] = np.log(df['Close']).diff()
```

it turned out to be useful as predictor but I'm a bit confused as what's happening.

A first order difference would correspond to an [approximation of the first derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference):

$\text{m}_t = \frac{f(x_{t}) - f(x_{t-1})}{x_{t} - x_{t-1}}\ \text{where}\ (x_{t} - x_{t-1})=1$

However, doing that after a log transformation is a bit trickier. The log would remove the heteroscedasticity or any multiplicative effect between the trend and seasonal components in a time-series with trend, seasonal and residual or error term.

If the original series is:

$x_t = m_t \dot\ s_t + z_t$

Then the log series becomes:

$\text{log}(x_t) = m_t + s_t + z_t'$

If I now apply a first order differencing I get the following:

$m_t + s_t + z_t' - m_{t-1} - s_{t-1} - z_{t-1}'$

Because the trend and seasonal components should be fairly close between $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$, then my log diff essentially is:

$z_t' - z_{t-1}'$

What does this mean?

Comment: Fundamentally, the diff-log series is a series of **returns**, so-called logarithmic returns. You thereby isolate (log) relative changes from correseponding levels. Furthermore, logarithmic returns allow for summation of return contributions, effectively allowing us to use the linear algebra toolbox for a lot of stuff. did that celar things a bit?

Comment: For small changes in price, log-returns approximate percentage returns.